# Swift: Saving photos to CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data

I need to save images downloaded from the Internet to CoreData.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return photos.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionPhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionCell
        let photo = photos[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    if let getImage = photo.getImage() {
        cell.photoImageView.image = getImage
    }
    else {
        // Photo Placeholder
        cell.photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: "imgPlaceholder.png")

        // Activity Indicator
        cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = false
        cell.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        FlickrClient().imageData(photo) {
            (imageData, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
        return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
        cell.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
        cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        cell.photoImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        }
      }
    }
    cell.photoImageView.alpha = 1.0
    return cell
}
```

Update:
In CoreData, the entity is Photos, and the Attribute is imageData. Looking at the code below, how does `managedObjectContext.save()`, save the downloaded images (in the collectionView) to CoreData? I'm still confused.

```
let photos = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Photo", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext!) as Photo
                do {
                    try managedObjectContext.save()
                } catch {
                    fatalError("Failure to save")
                }
```

Comment: You should show more code so we can understand what you are trying to do. Also you shouldn't be force unwrapping imageData

Comment: @RandyHill I updated the code. Force unwrapping is just for the moment.

Comment: In what way have you not been successful? What is happening or not happening that is not what you want?

Comment: @TomHarrington I just updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can get the managed object context from AppDelegate in this way:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:-
first we have to find image's path into your simulator's document directory using**

```
         let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
         let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("image.png")
          print(fileURL)
         if let data = image.pngData() {
            do {
                try data.write(to: fileURL)
                let imgPath = "\(fileURL)"
                imgCategoryPath = imgPath
            } catch {
                print("error saving file to documents:", error)
            }
```

**Step 2:-
second we have to retrive that image path from your simulator's document directory using**

```
    let nsDocumentDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let nsUserDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true)
    if let dirPath = paths.first{
        let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent(nameOfImage).absoluteString
        print(imageURL)
    }
```

**which path has got that store into core data in string formate column**

**Set Data**

```
do {
    try context.write(imageURL)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Read Data**

```
do {
    let imgString = try context.read(imageURL)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```